# The correct way to test 'SDL_PollEvent' in a 'while'

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

As the manual says, the function `SDL_PollEvent` "Returns 1 if there is a pending event or 0 if there are none available." , that's why we use the test `SDL_PollEvent(&e)!=0` (where `e` is a `SDL_Event`).

But, what about use this test: `!SDL_PollEvent(&e)`? It should work,but apparently it cause some problem.

Here an example of code:

```
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char* args[]){
      SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
      SDL_Window* window =   SDL_CreateWindow("Hello",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 100, 100,  SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
      SDL_Event e;
      int quit=0;
      while(!quit){
          //Here the test
          while (!SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
             if (e.type==SDL_QUIT)
                quit=1;
             else if ( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
                printf( "Hello\n" );
          }
      }
      SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
      SDL_Quit();
      return 0;
   }
```

What this code should do is open a new window and print "Hello" in the console every time a key is pressed. This code works fine whit the test `SDL_PollEvent(&e)!=0` but it doesn't read the `SDL_KEYDOWN` event when I use the test `!SDL_PollEvent(&e)` (but it DOES enter in the while and process the `SDL_QUIT` event without any problem).
Why this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
while (!SDL_PollEvent(&e))
```

needs to be:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
```

if it should be the same as `SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0`

because `!SDL_PollEvent(&e)` is the same as calling `while(0)`

Answer (score 3):

`(1 != 0)` is true, but `(!1)` is false.

You probably should use [`SDL_WaitEvent`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEvent) instead anyway.

Comment: `SDL_WaitEvent` is almost useless when there is only a single thread.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, it isn't. I don't consider not burning 100% CPU all the time on busy waiting "useless". Users of mobile devices will thank you.

Comment: You're right. But I have no idea how it can be used with single thread unless your appclitaion is completely passive and instantly reacts on input.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat By using timers and user-defined events. You install a timer that runs (for example) every 1/120 of a second. The timer calls your function, which posts an event to the queue. (you need user-defined events, because you can't do stuff directly in the timer function, see the manual)

Comment: Looks like you're right, timer events are only possible solution. Also, in fact, timer runs in a separate thread. :D

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well, the docs say it runs in the separate thread. It's vexing, because the separate thread shouldn't be needed for every platform - and, in fact, I don't think you need separate threads for timers on Windows in general (and AFAIR the alternative library to SDL, Allegro 5 doesn't use timers on separate threads.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I like to use PollEvent with SDL_Delay(1). If you make it run without the delay then it drains battery and it also causes the fans to run at max speed to cool off the CPU, which from a noise perspective is annoying for laptop users

Answer (score 0):

**Addendum**

One may think it's more clear to do something like this, since it ensures that user input is reacted upon. However, this is currently an OS dependent and possibly crazy CPU hog and will max out your CPU for this thread (on Windows). So you may think that you can just put a 1 second wait there, but then your window will become completely unresponsive or very laggy at best...
If you can live with a little CPU overhead for doing nothing, then you can compromise with using an 20-100 [ms] delay.

```cpp
...
    // Set the event handler...
    ...
    bool isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning) {
        // Do the main thing here...
        ...
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent)) {
            switch (windowEvent.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:              isRunning = false;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:           isRunning = false;
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:   isRunning = false;
                break;
            }
            SDL_Delay(100); // Wrong!
        }
    }
    // End the program
```

So clearly this is not the correct way either. We need to use some other mechanism. Looking at the SDL repo, we find a long but very relevant discussion for the open issue:

- [SDL_WaitEvent causes high cpu usage](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/3976)

---

**To Fix the issue**

Make sure you put the delay in the outer loop, before the `SDL_PollEvent()`.

```cpp
    // main loop
    ...
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent)) {
            switch (windowEvent.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:              isRunning = false;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:           isRunning = false;
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:   isRunning = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        SDL_Delay(100); // Right!
    }
```

Comment: The delay must be in the outer loop, not in the inner one. Preferably the delay should adapt to the time spent per frame, to maintain constant FPS.